How to include additional metadata (author, description) in JSON for blog posts in Docusaurus 3.1.1?
I'm currently working with Docusaurus for a blog, where each markdown file header includes metadata such as title and permalink. These are automatically synchronized and displayed on another page in my project. However, I'd like to also display the author and description fields from the markdown headers on this page.
Unfortunately, the default JSON file generated by Docusaurus only includes the title and permalink. When I add author and description to the markdown headers, they do not appear in the JSON file, which prevents me from syncing this additional information in my component.
How can I configure Docusaurus to include these additional metadata fields in the JSON output?

1) In markdown file:
---
title: The Perfect Match
authors: Jhon doe
tags: [perspective]
---

2) Json File

{
  "title": "Recent posts",
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "The Perfect Match",
      "permalink": "/blog/2024/04/18/the-perfect-match",
      "unlisted": false
    },
]}
3) my Component

import React from "react";
import Layout from "@theme/Layout";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import blogPosts from '../../../.docusaurus/docusaurus-plugin-content-blog/default/blog-post-list-prop-default.json'; // Ensure this path is correct
import "./blognew.css";



export default function AboutUS() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleRedirect = (permalink) => {
    history.push(permalink);
  };

  if (!blogPosts || !blogPosts.items || blogPosts.items.length === 0) {
    console.error('Blog posts data is missing or empty!');
    return <Layout><p>No blog posts available.</p></Layout>;
  }

//   const latestdesc = blogPosts.description; // The very latest post for the newblog-holder
  const latestPost = blogPosts.items[0]; // The very latest post for the newblog-holder
  const latestPosts = blogPosts.items.slice(1, 4); // Top 3 latest posts for the bottom section
    console.log(blogPosts.items);
  return (
    
    <Layout>

      <div className="newblog-holder">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {latestPost ? (
              <>
                <div className="col col--6">
                  <div className="newb minh">
                  <h1 onClick={() => handleRedirect(latestPost.permalink)}>{latestPost.title}</h1>
                  <h2>A {latestPost.author || "Anonymous"}</h2>
                  <p>{latestPost.description || "No description provided."}</p>
                    <button className="btn-more" onClick={() => handleRedirect(latestPost.permalink)}>Read More</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col col--6">
                  <div className="imgbox minh"></div>
                </div>
              </>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="blg-post">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col--12 text--start">
              <div className="desc-about">
                <h1>Our Blog Posts</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            {latestPosts.map((post, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="col col--4">
                <div className="desc-blg">
                  <div className="img-thumb">
                    <img src="/img/blog-thumb.jpg" alt="img"/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="desc-holder">
                    <div className="desc-box">
                    <h1 onClick={() => handleRedirect(post.permalink)}>{post.title}</h1>
                      <p>{post.description || "No description available."}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-more" onClick={() => handleRedirect(post.permalink)}>Read More</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}


How to include additional metadata (author, description) in JSON for blog posts in Docusaurus?
